# What does this bool operator actually do in C++? And how does this weird thing can be useful?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When I read C++ book I encountered with a strange operator !():

```
class myClass
{ 
     public:
bool operator !() const {}//What is it??
  };
```

Can someone explain me its purpose please.

Comment: It's the not operator. `bool b = true; bool bb = !b; // bb is false`

Comment: @Borgleader So it is overloading ! operator?

Comment: Over-loading `!` operator, using operator overloading

Comment: It's generally better to provide an `explicit operator bool()` so you can use it without negating it twice for being true.

Comment: Scroll down to "Boolean Operators" here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an ill-formed program, taken that `operator!` is declared to return `bool` but does not return anything. With that being fixed, it is the negation operator and it can be called on an object by prefixing `!`.

```
myClass c;
!c;         // c.operator!()
```

Comment: Can you please explain why ! operator does not return anything?

Comment: @HarryCater: Look at the definition: `{}`

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry me I'm a comlete dumb in C++.! operator should return bool?

Comment: @HarryCater it's declared as `bool operator !` so yes, it returns a bool

Comment: @HarryCater: For example, a correct implementation might replace the `{}` by something like `{ if (some_condition} return true; else return false; }` -- where the details depend on what `myClass` is and what it might mean to negate it.

Comment: The program is not ill-formed. However, the `operator!` has undefined behavior if it is ever called.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter: The standard explicitly states *Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function*, calling it undefined behavior as you mention. So not *ill-formed* in the standard sense. Yet, I would not call it *well-formed* (even if the standard does)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Or slightly better: `return some_condition;` I find all cases of `if (x) return true; else return false;` like aberrations. Why would anyone type so much to just say `return x;`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Agreed -- I was just trying to make it as clear as possible for Harry's sake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
myClass some_obj;
...
if (!some_obj) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: For example used in [`basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!), but I guess for historic reasons. More recent additions rather use `explicit operator bool`, like `shared_ptr`.